# how to undo hg update -C -r 3 command in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm a new user of tortoisehg and accidently I typed the command 'hg update -C -r 3' and a lot of files removed. Can I undo this command? I'm really desperate, thanks for any help and so sorry for poor English.

Comment: Were the files that were removed work you had not committed yet?

Comment: Does `hg update -r tip` bring them back? If you had uncommitted changes, they are probably lost.

Comment: Unless you have branches, just use `hg up`, and it will likely bring everything back. Otherwise, Edward is right.

Answer (score 0):

When you updated to an older revision, your TortoiseHg will probably look like this:

[image: example]

So you simply need to go to your tip (most recent revision) and click update. All your "lost" files will be "restored" again. The `""` are there because nothing is really lost just because you update to a different revision. Every revision is stored in the repository.

But wary that uncommitted changes will be lost when you update to a different revision, but you have to confirm that explicitly!